# How to get a Linux process run immediately after execv system call

Tags: linux, kernel, schedule, execv

The process (Android zygote) is forked from the init process, then call execv to load the real binary (/system/bin/app_process) to run.
As I check from the log time stamp, there is little delay between the fork and "execv system call return", but there is a signification delay (about 1s) between "execv system call return" and the "main() of app_process".

Looks like that the process is scheduled out after the execv system call, and get scheduled in some time later, causing the 1 second delay to the real main(). (Of cause, the loading of .so should also contribute to that 1 second).

My goal is to make this process run as soon as possible after the execv call. I have tried setting the highest priority -20 for the process after fork, the delay is reduced to 1 second but I still want further decrease.

Is there any way to get this process scheduled to run immediately after the execv system call return?

Answer (score 0):

Later on I dumped the schedule log of the target process and found that it already got scheduled right after the execv call, but it yielded off the CPU  soon due to a mm map page fault -- which indicating that it started loading the binaries. It needed to load so many libraries that it took almost one seconds before go to the main() function. So the question is in the wrong direction, the right direction is how to accelerate the loading, if possible.